# Questions about android code from a Udacity course

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have several questions about the following code. If you would take the time to answer them, that would be awesome.

`mForestAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);`. The object, mForestAdapter, takes four arguments. I am confused about the first three parameters.

1. What does getActivity() mean, what does it do, and why is it used here?
2. The tutorial indicated that I should create a new xml under the layout section called `list_item_forecast.xml`. And it is used as the third parameter. I'm not exactly sure why. Why create this new xml?
3. The third parameter is the id of the textView that is inside of `list_item_forecast.xml`. What does this textView do? What influence does this textView have? I tried to change the xml code in here and it just clears everything from the preview.

`ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);` What does rootView refer to and why do you need it here?

The code is as follows:

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ArrayAdapter<String> mForestAdapter;
        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/46",
                "Wednesday - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Thurs - Rainy - 64/51",
                "Fri - Foggy - 70/46",
                "Sat - Sunny - 76/68",
                "asdf",
                "asdfqwer",
                "qeprij",
                "qpweirj,"

        };

        ArrayList<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        mForestAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForestAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much you know about android development. 
"getActivity()" is a method from Fragment, and it's called because the ArrayAdapter constructor requires a "Context" to be passed.

I guess "list_item_forecast.xml" is the layout of each list element. This is not a must, but if this way you can "inflate" each list element from this xml.

If you don't understand anything of this you should first start with Google's documentation :

http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Then read about list adapters and what they do. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You will be cool if you can read Android reference for each questions you have. For ArrayAdapter, you can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

There are 6 constructors for ArrayAdapter and you can choose depend on your design and requirement. This is releted to your question.

> public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
>
> Parameters
>
> **context**   The current context.
>
> **resource**  The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.
>
> **textViewResourceId**    The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated
>
> **objects**   The objects to represent in the ListView.